# 3264 rational conics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, enumerative-geometry

It's a classical fact that there are 3264 plane conics tangent to 5 general conics, over $\mathbb{C}$ [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner's_conic_problem). It was also shown that the 3264 can be defined over the reals [[2]](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~sottile/3264/) or [[3]](http://www.mat.ucm.es/serv/revmat/vol10-2/vol10-2h.pdf). More precisely, they showed that there is a configuration of 5 real conics that admit 3264 real conics tangent at real points. 

I was wondering if analogous results are known over $\mathbb{Q}$ or finite extensions of it. More generally, over other non-algebraically closed fields of $\text{char}\ne 2$

Comment: The result over $\mathbf{C}$ is geometric -- it holds over any algebraically closed field of char 0. In particular there must exist such a configuration over some finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: This may be relevant: 
Vakil, Ravi
Schubert induction.  
Ann. of Math. (2) 164 (2006), no. 2, 489–512.